# How to handle UserControl inside a window when the window size changed

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, window-resize

I have a main window written in WPF that contains three sub windows and a user control with buttons. It looks like this:
[image: my window]

What I want to do is to have the sub windows' ratio and the buttons' position fixed proportionally with the main window resizing.

I've handled the sub windows' size ratio, but I can't keep the buttons on the left side when the main widow's width is expanded:

[image: window size larger]

And here is my code:

```cs
private void MainWindowResize(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // sub windows size ratio
    formA.Height = (this.ActualHeight - 80) * 0.5;
    formA.Width = this.ActualWidth;
    formB.Height = (this.ActualHeight - 80) * 0.5;
    formB.Width = this.ActualWidth * 0.5;
    formC.Height = (this.ActualHeight - 80) * 0.5;
    formC.Width = this.ActualWidth * 0.5;
    
    // buttons will not move to the left with this code
    btnFrame.Width = this.ActualWidth;
}
```

+) WPF code:
MainWindow

```xml
<Grid x:Name="maingrid">
    <DockPanel x:Name="panel1" LastChildFill="false">
        <Frame DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="35" Width="800" Source="pack://application:,,,/FormBottom;component/form_bottom.xaml" />
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="formA" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="207" Width="800" >
            <wftop:form_top x:Name="formTop" Dock="Fill"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="formB" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="207" Width="400" >
            <wflt:form_left x:Name="formLeft" Dock="Fill"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="formC" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="207" Width="400">
            <wfrt:form_right x:Name="formRight" Dock="Fill"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel x:Name="panel2" LastChildFill="false" >
        <Frame DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="35" Width="800" Source="pack://application:,,,/FormBottom;component/form_bottom.xaml" />
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

btnFrame

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="FormBottom.form_bottom"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FormBottom"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Height="35" Width="800">
    <StackPanel x:Name="bottompanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Button Content="Panel1" MinWidth="70" Click="Button_Click" />
        <Button Content="Panel2" MinWidth="70" Click="Button_Click_1" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Is there a way to have the buttons fixed on the left?

Comment: [WPF Layout system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/layout?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) -- [DockPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.dockpanel). Btw, do you mean you have a WPF Window that's hosting WinForms' UserControls (or Forms, not exactly clear)? In any case, you don't need to handle all this *manually*. See also the `Auto` Height/Width, the `HorizontalAlignmen` and `VerticalAlignment` can be set to `Stretch` etc.

Comment: Also [Alignment, Margins, and Padding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/alignment-margins-and-padding-overview)

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for your comment. Yeah, exactly. MainWindow is a WPF Window, formA, B, C WinForms, and btnFrame a UserControl. I've checked those you suggested, but I'm still stuck on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of control the `btnFrame` is but you can put the buttons inside of a e.g. `StackPanel` and set the `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` on it.
Your WPF code would be helpful to provide a better answer.

After you've posted your WPF I think you should just remove the `Width="800"` attribute from your `Frame` so that it always stretches to fit its containing `DockPanel`. Besides I can't see where the `btnFrame` name is set in the WPF.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've added my WPF code to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have size control on your own. WPF provides [various `Panel`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/panels-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#user-interface-panels) for layouting out-of-the-box and there are also panels for proportional layouts like [`Grid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid?view=net-5.0) or [`DockPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.dockpanel?view=net-5.0).

Your example could look like this in XAML. The `Rectangle`s represent your views. Using `Grid` panel you can define rows and columns and via their [`RowDefinition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.rowdefinition?view=net-5.0) and [`ColumnDefinition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.columndefinition?view=net-5.0) you can set `Height` and `Width` to either explicit sizes, e.g. `100`, let the size be determined automatically to fit the content with `Auto` or set star-sizes like `2*` which lets you define proportions. The default value is `*` so in the layout below, the last row sizes to its content and the other rows are sized in proportion 1:1.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="Pink"/>
   <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Fill="MediumSeaGreen"/>
   <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Fill="LightBlue"/>
   <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Button Content="A" Width="100" Height="50"/>
      <Button Content="B" Width="100" Height="50" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

You can achieve the same layout with different panels, so this is just an example. What is the most suitable approach depends on your requirements and preferences. The same layout in code:

```
var grid = new Grid();

grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });

grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

var pinkRectangle = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle { Fill = Brushes.Pink };
grid.Children.Add(pinkRectangle);
Grid.SetRow(pinkRectangle, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(pinkRectangle, 0);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(pinkRectangle, 2);

var greenRectangle = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle { Fill = Brushes.MediumSeaGreen };
grid.Children.Add(greenRectangle);
Grid.SetRow(greenRectangle, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(greenRectangle, 0);

var blueRectangle = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle { Fill = Brushes.LightBlue };
grid.Children.Add(blueRectangle);
Grid.SetRow(blueRectangle, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(blueRectangle, 1);

var buttonA = new Button
{
   Content = "A",
   Width = 100,
   Height = 50
};

var buttonB = new Button
{
   Content = "B",
   Width = 100,
   Height = 50,
   Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0)
};

var stackPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
grid.Children.Add(stackPanel);
Grid.SetRow(stackPanel, 2);
Grid.SetColumn(stackPanel, 0);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(stackPanel, 2);

stackPanel.Children.Add(buttonA);
stackPanel.Children.Add(buttonB);
```

Comment: Thanks for your example! I understand what you mean. But I still can't find a solution to control size when I'm hosting WinForms and UserControl from other projects.